# how to write query for split two rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have order table

```
OrderId OrderStatusId  CurrencyId      PromotionCode
------------------------------------------------------
  137         5           1             123a-123d
  138         5           1             123a-123d-234c
```

I want to split the `PromotionCode` column like this:

Result:

```
OrderId  OrderStatusId  CurrencyId  PromotionCode
-----------------------------------------------------
  137             5             1             123a
  137             5             1             123d
  138             5             1             123a
  138             5             1             123d
  138             5             1             234c
```

Please help me ...

is it possible to do... any way plz help me asas possible....

Comment: If you post code, XML or fixed-width tables and stuff like that, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the promotion codes are always 4 characters long, the simplest way is probably a union:

```
select  id, substring(code,1,4)
from    YourTable
where   LEN(code) >= 4
union all
select  id, substring(code,6,4)
from    YourTable
where   LEN(code) >= 9
union all
select  id, substring(code,11,4)
from    YourTable
where   LEN(code) >= 14
<etc>
```

For a more flexible solution, have a look at one of the various [Split functions](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx).  After creating this function in your database, you can invoke it like:

```
select  t.id, s.items
from    YourTable t
cross apply   
        dbo.Split(t.code,'-') s
```

Both queries will produce the result as requested in your answer.

Comment: Can u explain how to use split function to do same result abow i created .... help me soon

Comment: @jay: Example use of Split added to answer